# return back page the display none but got display block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom

i have 2 radio buttons, one for `section 1` and one for `section 2`,

and the default selected radion button is `section 1`, and showing some text, but when the client clicked the `section 2` there are no text below. that is for illustration my page

```
[*] section 1                 [ ] section 2


- section one text when checked radio button

----------------------------------------------
[ ] section 1                 [*] section 2

// none text here when section two checked



< Button >
```

when then after click button and choose section 2 , and go to another page, and then return back to that section page, the text of `section one text when checked radio button` showing thought the radio button check the `section 2`

how to hide that text (`section one text when checked radio button`) when client return to that page but the checked on `section 2` still checked ?

this happend on my Rails app

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the span containing the text based on the value of your variables. For example, you could make this:

```
<span class="<%= hide if @variable =='section 2 value' %>">
  - section one text when checked radio button
</span>
```

Comment: i do onCLick this  on javascript file and the default is section 1, what variable u mean?

Comment: How do you add those radio buttons in the view? Can you add the Rails code you used for that?

Answer (score 0):

IF I guess what you want to do correctly:  It's something with showing text based on which radio button is clicked.  How about splitting the HTML up into divs and showing/hiding the ids of those two divs onlick.

When section 1 is clicked:

```
$('#add-doc-modal #show-section1').show();
$('#add-doc-modal #show-section2').hide();
```

When section 2 is clicked:

```
$('#add-doc-modal #show-section2').show();
$('#add-doc-modal #show-section1').hide();
```

IF this is your issue I mean it's not the easiest to read that.

To hide radio buttons and set checked false:

```
document.getElementById("#id").style.display = "none";
$("#id").prop("checked", false);
```

To show radio buttons

```
document.getElementById("#id").style.display = "block";
$("#id").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: I'm editing answer.  Really hard to understand you btw.